# setting a tight bounding box when amsmath symbols touch it

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bounding-box

I would like the straight lines to end exactly ON the line of the various `\circ`. Red boxes show why this doesn't happen: `\circ` has more space below it then above (Please, note that *still a white space is present between lower circles and the lines ending on them*. Simply remove the red box to check this).
I tried with `inner sep=-.75` for upper cicles and `inner sep=-.3` for lower cicles, but this makes the bounding box cut out a part of the upper ones and still leaves a white space under the lower ones.

If you are wandering why I use `\circ` and not draw a `circle`, the answer is that `\circ` is text and doesn't scale with the image (indeed I don't want it to!). Moreover I can refer to this symbols in-line simply writing `$\circ$` with no new tikzpicture every few lines..

The MWE is the following

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}


\newcommand{\mat}{\mathbf}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\bm}

\begin{document}


   \begin{tikzpicture}

      %\useasboundingbox ($(1,-.5)-(.1,.2)$) rectangle ($(4,.5)+(.1,.2)$);

      \draw (1,0) -- (4,0); % linea centrale

      \foreach \x in {1,...,4} % ciclo sui cerchi
      {
         \draw (\x,0) -- +(0,.5);
         \node[black,draw=red,very thin,fill=white,inner sep=0] at (\x,.5) {$\circ$};
      }
      \foreach \x in {1.5,2.5,...,3.5} % ciclo sulle barrette
      {
         \draw (\x,0) -- +(0,-.5);
         \node[black,draw=red,very thin,fill=white,inner sep=0] at (\x,-.5) {$\circ$};
      }
      %\node[left] at (2.5,-.5) {1};

      %\draw[dashed,red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
   \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is because `\circ` glyph has white space around. Check with another character in place and you will see (for example a dot). One workaround is, if you really need a node, is to put `\tikz\draw circle(2pt);` in place of `$\circ$`. By the way your code is not MWE : a lot of libraries are not necessary here. And one more suggestion, the package `calc` is not the same thing as the tikz library `calc`.

Comment: You can try this command `\draw(0.5,0)--+(3,0)foreach[evaluate={\i=2*mod(\x,2)-1}]\x in{1,...,7}{(\x/2,0)--+(0,.5*\i)node[draw=red,very thin,fill=white,inner sep=0] {\tikz\draw circle(2pt);}};`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the bottom of `\circ` is above the baseline.  You can either raise the baseline using `\raisebox`, or use `\Circle` from the `wasysym` package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}


\newcommand{\mat}{\mathbf}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\bm}
\newcommand{\mycirc}{\raisebox{-.11ex}[\dimexpr\height-.11ex][0pt]{$\circ$}}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}

      %\useasboundingbox ($(1,-.5)-(.1,.2)$) rectangle ($(4,.5)+(.1,.2)$);

      \draw (1,0) -- (4,0); % linea centrale

      \foreach \x in {1,...,4} % ciclo sui cerchi
      {
         \draw (\x,0) -- +(0,.5);
        \node[black,draw=red,very thin,fill=white,inner sep=0] at (\x,.5) {\Circle};
      }
      \foreach \x in {1.5,2.5,...,3.5} % ciclo sulle barrette
      {
         \draw (\x,0) -- +(0,-.5);
        \node[black,draw=red,very thin,fill=white,inner sep=0] at (\x,-.5) {\Circle};
      }
      %\node[left] at (2.5,-.5) {1};

      %\draw[dashed,red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
   \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: \Circle substitution]